# Can't access property of Vuex store object

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js, vuex, vuex-modules

I initialize my store with a JSON file entitled `config.json`:

```
{
  "branding": {
    "button": {
      "secondary": {
        "background_color": "#EC6B24",
        ...
      },
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

... which I import in my store:

```
import templateConfig from '@/config.json'

export const state = () => ({
  branding: {}
})

export const mutations = {
  setConfig (state, data) {
    state.branding = templateConfig.branding
  }
}

export const actions = {
  initializeStore ({ state, commit }, data) {
    commit('setConfig', data)
  }
}
```

Now in my view's `mounted` hook, I call my store action (`this.initializeStore()`) so that the store gets populated on page load.

Problem is, when in one of my view's child components I try to access a nested property like so:

```
computed: {
  ...mapState({
    bgColor: state => state.template.branding.button.secondary.background_color
  })
}
```

... I'm getting this error:

> Cannot read property 'secondary' of undefined

Why?

EDIT: below is the parent view component's code.

```
import { mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default {
  mounted () {
    this.initializeStore()
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions({
      initializeStore: 'initializeStore'
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you `await this.initializeStore()` in the mounted hook ?

Comment: Nope, `initializeStore()` is called from the parent view component anyway. I just tried to use `await` and `async` there but it doesn't help.

Comment: You should show the parent component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means the state only has its initial value at that time, and the action wasn't called yet (the parent is mounting after the child maps the state).  You could try the action in the parent's `created` hook instead.

However, if `initializeStore` is only called once at initialization, you can remove that action (and mutation) altogether, and just define your `state` from the imported json directly:

```js
import templateConfig from '@/config.json'

export const state = () => ({
  branding: templateConfig.branding
})
```

The action / mutation never use the payload anyway.

If data was being fetched rather than imported, I would suggest to look into [`nuxtServerInit`](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/store/#the-nuxtserverinit-action) and/or `fetch` / `asyncData` hooks.

Comment: Thanks @shob. You're right with `created` hook it works! Just one thing: this JSON file is temporary and eventually I'll be indeed fetching data so the last bit of your answer is spot on. But it'll also be a static site, will `fetch` still work? ([doc](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/data-fetching/) isn't very clear on this)

Comment: You're welcome.  If you use deployment `target: static`, then `fetch` is called at build time (i.e. `generate`), and the data is bundled with the app.  `fetch` won't be called again during navigation

Comment: You can also [exclude](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-generate/#exclude) some pages from static so that they do call fetch in production, but they will be client-side rendered. Read more [here](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/concepts/static-site-generation/#generating-your-site), [here](https://nuxtjs.org/blog/going-full-static/), and [here](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1500#issuecomment-326043106)